# QGIS expression on legend for duplicated values

Tags: qgis, print-composer, legend, expression

Having a building table, grouped by an `id` and its respective amount of apartments. I want to label every symbol id on map composer legend with the amount of apartments.

[image]

For a simple expression `'apartments'`, nothing appears regarding amount of apartments neither any field inserted on expression.

I think issue comes because table has building level and all values regarding symbol id are repeated for the buildings are grouped on each id.

Even for repeated amounts I have written the expression: `concat( @symbol_label, ': ',apartments)` which avoid any repeated value and is not working. Legend appears as in the image from above. Is weird because on expression window the expression returns value (`178`),

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you want to sum all the apartments for each group? for example you have 7 rows with 161 apartments and id 1, you want the legend label to be "1127 apts"?

Comment: No, sum is already done on apartments field. As it can be seen on map image, every building has its own information, like a correlative sum of apartments regarding a specific geometric order. I'm saying this because I can't work with a non repeated values for id and apartments

Comment: So you are looking for `count("id","id")` (second "id" is the group by clause) which counts the amount of same id's?

Comment: mmm... no. I just want to label apartments field in the legend. Seems very simple but it doesn't work with a simple expression 'apartments'

Comment: Ok, now I get it. Which field did you choose for your classification?

Comment: if you mean on the legend: apartments

Comment: Now I am confused again. If you would have chosen apartments as your classifier, then you already would have your desired result? Except for the case two different ids have the same amount of apartments as result...

Comment: Probably is why I'm asking. I don't get it either... Even for repeated amounts I have written the expression:  concat( @symbol_label, ': ',apartments) which avoid any repeated value and is not working. Legend appears as in the image from above. Is weard because on expression window the expression returns value (178)

Answer (score 6):

Obviously, you can not use a `field` in print composer legend. Only `@symbol_id`, `@symbol_count` and `@symbol_label` will work. And of course all normal expressions, we will come to them at the end of this answer.

So the easiest solution seems to be to leave your print composer and go back to your main QGIS canvas. Open the layer properties, go to symbology and categorize your layer again with this expression: `"id" || ': ' || "apartments"`.

[image]

*(Indeed, it would be way nicer if one could choose an expression for the legend, but seems like that is not the case. There is most likely some neat Python solution possible though..)*

If you now go back to your composer, you can simply add the legend:

[image]

If you do not wish to display the "id"s you can use some other expressions like `regex_substr()` or `right()`, e.g. `right(@symbol_label,3)` or more robust `regexp_substr(@symbol_label,'[^\\s]*$')`, which matches all characters after a whitespace:

[image][image]

Which results in:

[image]

Comment: Great! Definetely works! Even regex did its job ;)